# Loading Speed with hidden iframe

Tags: html, css, performance, iframe, render

Does a hidden iframe makes the page loading smoother. It obviously has to be loaded but not rendered, right? Does this affect the user experience in terms of speed if the iframe is "display: none" or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this question mate. It might answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351360/should-i-load-a-hidden-iframe-in-the-beginning

Comment: @Jack Is this your question or his? Seems like it helped him out mate.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble I would have said "@Donte'Trumble" if that was directed at your comment. He asked a yes or no question, and I could not comment with just a "No." My full answer would be "Not that a user would notice" but I was being a smart a*